# Docker-compose: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/node/logs/accounts-service-2023-10-15.log'

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I had an application running on an EC2 instance which was working perfectly but the private key has been lost so we cannot access the server for any maintenance. Therefore, I took an image from the instance and created a new EC2 using the saved AMI. It is my understanding that this is an exact duplication of the original EC2 instance. Obviously I do have access to this instance as I created it.

It has an HAProxy webserver and 6 docker containers, but one of the containers keeps restarting because of a permissions error. I do not understand why this is an issue as the original instance must have had this container running and the permissions should be the same. Anyway, here is my docker-compose file:

```
    version: "2"
services:
  #haproxy:
  #  image: haproxy:1.8-alpine
  #  volumes:
  #   - ./app/resources/haproxy/haproxy-container.new.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy-container.new.cfg
  #   - ./app/resources/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
  #  ports:
  #   - 8082:8082
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
     - ./test/fixtures/infrastructure_structure.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
     - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
     - 3308:3306
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=xxxxxxxxxx
  service:
    image: node:6.14.4-alpine
    restart: always
    working_dir: /home/node
    entrypoint: "node ./app/app.js"
    mem_limit: "300M"
    memswap_limit: "1G"
    ports:
     - "${APP_PORT}:13003"
    volumes:
     - .:/home/node
     - ./logs:/home/node/logs
    user: node
    depends_on:
     - mysql
    # - haproxy
    links:
     - mysql
    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=production
     - SERVICE_ROUTE=infrastructure
     - DEBUG=*
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nowce-temp-network
```

Here are my running (one restarting) docker containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                                NAMES
9e405ef44a3c        node:6.14.4-alpine    "node ./app/app.js"      17 hours ago        Restarting (1) 3 hours ago   0.0.0.0:13003->13003/tcp             nowce-infrastructure_service_1
4bc7dd4a153b        mysql:5.7             "docker-entrypoint.sh"   20 hours ago        Up 20 hours                  33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3306/tcp    nowce-infrastructure_mysql_1
e539326f97ba        node:16.19-alpine     "node ./app/app.js --"   34 hours ago        Up 23 hours                  0.0.0.0:20000->13001/tcp             nowce-service_service_1
d873909f7800        redis:4.0.11-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   34 hours ago        Up 23 hours                  6379/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20001->26379/tcp   nowce-service_redisdb_1
1da9e22fabd8        node:6.14.4-alpine    "node ./app/app.js"      4 years ago         Up 23 hours                  0.0.0.0:13002->13002/tcp             nowce-accounts_service_1
c07153370d75        mysql:5.7             "docker-entrypoint.sh"   4 years ago         Up 23 hours                  33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp    nowce-accounts_mysql_1
```

and here is the error message, or at least the last part from the log from 'nowce-infrastructure_service_1' container:

```
Sun, 15 Oct 2023 07:32:07 GMT express:router:layer new '/infrastructure/ism/webhook'
Sun, 15 Oct 2023 07:32:07 GMT express:router:route post '/infrastructure/ism/webhook'
Sun, 15 Oct 2023 07:32:07 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
listening on port:  13003
**** App started ****
2023-10-15T07:32:07.203Z
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/node/logs/accounts-service-2023-10-15.log'
    at Error (native)
```

The file '/home/node/logs/accounts-service-2023-10-15.log' does not exist, in fact the directory '/home/node/logs/' does not exist but '/home/node/' does. I have changed the permission already on '/home/node/' by running the command:

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/node/logs
```

I still get the same error. When I start this docker container on my local (development environment) machine I do not get this error.

Does anyone know what else to check?

Comment: In an EC2 context, I wonder if this setup would be easier to run with an RDS database and running Node directly on the host.  You're not building a reusable image but rather deploying code directly to the server, using Docker just as a path to get a Node interpreter.  Removing Docker from the picture might help simplify the permission problem you're running into.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the docker-compose as I had updated the wrong version.